# How to retrieve required data from an excel file into matlab (R2015 a) ?

Tags: excel, matlab

```
function sample()
[FileName,FilePath]=uigetfile();
ExPath = [FilePath FileName];
f=xlsread(ExPath); 
[R C]=size(f);
disp(R);
disp(C);
Y=f(R+1:R:R*C);
X=f(2:1:R);
Z=f(2:1:R,2:1:C);
disp(Y);
```

The above is a sample code that reads data from a excel file.I have no idea how the indexing is done.

disp(Y) seems to output the values of the 1st row .

Can anyone please explain how the above indexing works.

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html covers how `xlsread` works, https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html covers matrix indexing in some depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab stores n-dimensional arrays by column, then row, then each higher dimension in turn.

```
f = [1 2; 3 4]; ' an example
f(1,1); ' returns 1
f(2,1); ' returns 3
f(1,2); ' returns 2
f(2); 'returns 3
f(1,:); ' returns [1 2]
f(2,1:1:2); 'returns [3 4];
f(:,1); 'returns [1; 3]
f(1:1:4); 'returns [1 3 2 4]
f(f>1); 'returns [3 2 4]
f(R+1:R:R*C); 'returns 2 - the first row starting at the 2nd column.
```